# Jquery get value of a text field of the form being submitted when there are multiple forms on the page

Tags: jquery

```
    <form class="userControl">
        <input type="hidden" class="userName" name="userName" value="john759">
        <button class="action">Block</button>
    </form>

    <form class="userControl">
        <input type="hidden" class="userName" name="userName" value="dDuck">
        <button class="action">Block</button>
    </form>

    <form class="userControl">
        <input type="hidden" class="userName" name="userName" value="cCrow">
        <button class="action">Block</button>
    </form>

    $(".userControl").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var user = $(".userName").val();

        alert(user);

if(user) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
             url:"/user-control/",
            data:data,
        dataType:'json',

        beforeSend:function(html) {

        },

//etc

    });
```

In a situation when there are multiples forms on a page, what is the correct and surest method to get the value of the text field of only the form being submitted?

Right now, even if I click the last form, I get the value of the first one.

The form is submitted using `GET` and the `userName` is what is passed to the php script.

Answer (score 0):

You give it some context. You have a reference to the form in the submit handler with the `this` variable. So you can simply do:

```
$(".userControl").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var user = $(this).find(".userName").val();
    // other stuff
});
```